# Update Local MS SQL Table from Linked Server (MySQL) Table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, linked-server, openquery

I'm trying to update a local MSSQL Table from a Linked Server Table (MySQL).

The tables on both the servers have identical columns.The only difference between these tables is  the name of MSSQL Table is `employer` and the name of MySQL Table is `employees` .Both have 4 columns named `id`, `col1`, `col2` and `[datetime]`.

I'm trying to update the rows of the MSSQL `employer` table from the MySQL Table where rows have not same values based upon a key (let's say `id`).

Basically, when the MySQL table is updated, I'm trying to update the MSSQL employers table. They need to be identical.

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: *Basically, when the MySQL table is updated...* Are you trying to write an UPDATE statement or have some process that runs that keeps these tables in sync?

Comment: An Update statement might work... And I have tried quite a few options... A sync process would definitely work if possible... Im able to add rows from the MySQL table to the MSSQL Table without issue... its UPDATING that's giving me the headache